# Increment madness

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I'm currently writing a compiler for the C-language, and stumbled upon something rather peculiar. I know that the increment operator `++` can be prefix or postfix, I know that it can be used in expressions.

- So the line: `a++`, where `a` is an integer variable, should be legal.
- The line: `(a++)-(++b)` should also be legal.
- The line: `a++-++b` is also legal.
- The line: `a++/++b` is also legal.

This leads me to conclude that: 
`<variable><++><operator><++><variable>`, where operator is any binary operator should be legal.

What confuses me, is that the line `a+++++b` is not legal. Why is this not legal? Is it something to do with how GCC lexes the expression `a+++++b`?

---

I'm running GCC 7.2.0.

Comment: I'm afraid I flagged this by mistake. This is about the lexicographical analysis of C, not the semantics.

Comment: This is not the correct duplicate. This is the one to do with the fact that ++++a is not valid C (but is valid C++).

Comment: Explaining grotcode is not useful to future SO users/visitors:(

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, I didn't know what to search for in order to find the any duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The problem is that C tokenizer must consume as much characters as possible, so `a+++++b` is lexed as `a++ ++ + b` which is not valid C.

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate and also a somewhat common FAQ. See the nice answer by Shafik Yaghmour in the linked duplicate. I've added the linked post to the [SO C FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) now.